# Phone 5 tab bar not working - iOS7 and Xcode GM's

Tags: ios7, xcode5

My app builds fine on my 4s and the Simulator for 3.5" screens but the tab bar doesn't function at all when I build on the iPhone 5 and the Simulator.  There are no relevant diagnostics and yes the builds succeed.

Any idea where to start figuring out this new problem? My app is ready to submit to the App Store other than this issue.

Comment: You'll have to give some more information on the problem past doesn't function. What about it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that it seems in MainWindow.xib for Window you do not have "Full Screen at Launch" setted to On.

Try this - it should work fine.